# massageFormValues not being run on custom form

Tags: forms

I've built a widget for my custom field and this works OK when I create / update a "normal" node edit via the normal D10 content interface & forms.

I've added this widget to a custom form like so

```
$section = 'field_my_fieldname';
$entity_form_display = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('entity_form_display')->load('node.prelims.default');
$widget = $entity_form_display->getRenderer($section);
$form[$section]  = $widget->form($items, $form, $formstate);
```

The form displays as expected, it picks up all the functionality in the widget saving duplication of the widget code, however, when I try to get the results in the submitForm() function using

```
$form_state->getValue($section)
```

The results appear as though the widget's massageFormValues() has not been run as the values are in their un-massaged structure from the widget. Is there any way to force widget massageFormValues to be run as it is run from the default D10 node edit form?

Comment: By "force" do you mean get something else to execute it on your behalf? If so then I would've thought the answer will be "no" - as you're taking the field out of an entity form you'll need to give it the extra functionality the entity form would otherwise have given it. [`WidgetBase::extractFormValues()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21WidgetBase.php/function/WidgetBase%3A%3AextractFormValues/10) looks like it might be enough to serve as an example of massaging the values and filtering empty items out of it

Comment: Apologies for delay in responding, I had a day off. By "force", I was wanting to make the massageFormValues function get called in the same way as if I was editing the field in the usual node edit process. I'll explore your suggestion.